# AS - ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I got a problem here when I navigated the button symbol in code snippet, after I chose "Click to Go to Frame and Stop", I got some codes:

```
Photos.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_Photos);

function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_Photos(event:MouseEvent):void
{
gotoAndStop(4);
}
```

Orginally the codes were with something like "...fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_17", it was system automatically generated, but it did not work when I left it unchanged, then I changed to the name as same as the button's name (Photos), as a result, it was working to navigate to the right frame, however, I do not know why. I also tried to rename the button:

```
Button3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_3);

function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_3(event:MouseEvent):void
{
gotoAndStop(4);
}
```

It is only working when I put "_3" after "ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame", do not know why either, please advise my issues above, very appreciated.

Comment: asterisks is not a valid character to use in variable/function names.   Take out all the * and then try again  (or is that you trying to bold the code?)   I'm having a hard time understanding your question

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, the ** is not with the code, I just wanna try to hightlight the problem areas, please check my edited ones above, thanks

Comment: When you say system generated,  what is generating it?  When you say "did not work"  what is the error or undesired result?

Comment: it generated the codes I provided, but the character after "fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame.." was changed by me, because it was something like fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_17", I do not know what is the character here mean, I changed it to "fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_Photos", then it is working, so I do not know what the character is about...

Comment: do you have the same code on multiple frames?